# How can I send data to the STDIN of a background process?

Tags: ssh, process, io-redirection

I'm trying to:

- Launch several `ssh` sessions (processes) through a script (Python)
- Communicate with the sessions by sending them commands via STDIN (even though they aren't open in my current terminal)

I've got the session spawning part down. I'm just unable to grab the process and send it stuff. I should mention this is a realm I've only recently started delving in so I'm definitely missing theory.

**Explanation:**

In-depth what I'm trying to do is launch `ssh` WITHOUT a terminal (I'm already doing this with python, so that isn't the issue) in the background. My problem arises when I actually want to communicate with the background process. How can I send data to a background process' STDIN?

Comment: By sending the `ssh` processes commands, do you mean arguments like i.e. `-vvv`? I guess you'll need to have each process listen to some specific socket (possibly `stdin`) to which you can direct all your messages.

Comment: No I mean starting an `ssh` session (logging into another server). Then sending commands to `ssh` through STDIN to the remote server.

Comment: It may be better if you describe what exactly you are trying to accomplish, so people can suggest ways to do it.  Otherwise, it just sounds like you are looking for `ssh host command-list`.

Comment: @jw013 I added some info. Hopefully I'm communicating my question correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be easier to use a named pipe to communicate with the processes than try to modify the FD whilst it's open. Set the named pipe as the process' standard input and write to it as required.

Comment: Makes sense. I didn't know you had to modify the file descriptor to get at the STD streams. Thanks Chris.

Comment: @MaxMackie - Well, `stdin`/`stdout`/`stderr` are all merely naming abstractions of file descriptors on POSIX-compliant systems.