# Write to stdin of running process on occasion

Tags: process, stdin, netcat, fifo

From time to time I want to send some text to the input of `netcat`. Netcat will send it then to another netcat process (either on my machine or a local network), but now I am only concerned with the first one.

E.g. on keypress the user fills a value in a prompt; I want to send that value to that process.

---

Given the value in, say `$text`, **how do I send it to `netcat` so that it receives it and treats it just like normal stdin?**

---

I've tried the following ways, none of them work:

- `` echo $text >> /proc/`pidof netcat`/fd/0 ``.
  This writes `$text` to the terminal but netcat does not receive it. (according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374255/how-to-write-data-to-existing-processs-stdin-from-external-process))

  - I also tried starting netcat like this: `cat | netcat ...` and echo-ing to the `cat` process
- `mkfifo pipe; 
  netcat <mypipe`
  Now, when the other netcat process connects, it receives what I have sent to `mypipe` so far.
  Any further writes to `mypipe` have no effect.

  - I also tried `cat mypipe | netcat ...`
    This had a different result: the first write to `mypipe` is sent to the other netcat process, but the second `echo 123 >mypipe` attempt freezes - I do not get the prompt and I can enter values but nothing happens.

---

As I just learned about named pipes, I might not be using the correctly.
But looking for "stream files" or simmilar [tells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32061/how-can-i-send-data-to-the-stdin-of-a-background-process) me they are the right tool for this job (but not *how*).

The alternative to my first attempt (I learned about this on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/178457/can-i-send-some-text-to-the-stdin-of-an-active-process-running-in-a-screen-sessi)) was to use `screen` but I think it's overkill for my problem.

The issue with the named pipes [seems to be](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139490/continuous-reading-from-named-pipe-cat-or-tail-f) that `echo` sends EOF after the string. In turn, `netcat` stopps reading from the pipe and therefore I can't send any more messages (I can, but netcat doesn't read them). This led me to [Piping data to a process's stdin without causing EOF afterward](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103885/piping-data-to-a-processs-stdin-without-causing-eof-afterward), but I don't see how to apply the provided solution to my case.

I think I covered any possible combination of pipes/cats/echoes without result so the only thing left was unix.se :)

Thanks in advance!